# What is the most pythonic type to use when creating a dataset purely for reference in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, set, tuples

If I want to have a dataset against which to check values, what is the best type of dataset to use in Python.

For example:

I have five fruits.  To store those I can either store them in a set, a tuple or a list.

```
fruits_set = {'Apples','Bananas','Oranges','Pears','Blueberries'}
fruits_tuple = ('Apples','Bananas','Oranges','Pears','Blueberries')
fruits_list = ['Apples','Bananas','Oranges','Pears','Blueberries']
```

I acknowledge that there are reasons given specific contextual use that might point you towards using one type over the other.

However, if the specific use case was just to be for the below:

```
fruit = 'Apple'

if fruit in fruits_set:

   print('Fruit is in the dataset!')
```

I have just used the fruits_set as the example, but it could have been the fruits_tuple or the fruits_list.  This is the question.  If this is the entire use of the dataset, which dataset type is the most suitable here?  Or is there really not much to it other than a question of style?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a `set` is used to store unique items and also can be changed [aka mutable], a `list` is a typical array that can be modified [aka mutable] and a `tuple` is a frozen array, just like `list` but cannot be changed [aka immutable].
If you want to have the advantages of `set` (Uniqueness, fast-`in` [O(1) in `set` instead of O(n) in `tuple`/`list`, thanks to hashes] and more), but on the other hand you want it to be immutable, you can use `frozenset`.

Even though iterating over a list seems to be the most fast.